# Click event not working for Firefox but is for chrome

Tags: c#, selenium

The click event is not firing in firefox but works ok in chrome. 
The test fails with the error: "Element not found on page."

Below is the code and HTML for the button I want to click.

```
Browser.ElementClickById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_lvProducts_ctrl0_ctrl1_btnAddProductToCart_input");
```

and inside the elementclickbyid i have:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementID)).Click();
```

HTML code is:

event

Comment: What does "not working" mean? An error or ? Edit your question and add these details. Also, please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output and any exception messages.

Comment: Please paste html code instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try working around with a Javascript click.

```
// declare JS executor
var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;

// locate the input
var input = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='submit']"));

// execute JS to click
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", input);
```

I've seen cases where regular `Click();` does not work across browsers -- these cases are rare, but using JS click usually works across multiple browsers when I run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

i am sure you are trying to use browser class to keep your methods there, but try to use xpath not id. just use this code to click what you need. don't use page object model or anything else. don't save it in your browser class under click method. just in your main code use this code to click. and before to run it make sure that you have only one type submit. if its gonna show to you 2 types then use this code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit'][1]")).click();
```

number 1 says click to first submit if the button which you need second then follow the logic and change the number to 2

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit'][2]")).click();
```

for better answer share your code class and also URL where you are trying to click button and also which element you are trying to click

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Said Yusifli, i tried doing it by xpath but it still failed. however i added the javascript from above and that approach has worked for me.